# TypeError: validate() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given (Automata lib)

Tags: python, automata, dfa

Can someone help me with this error, i have spend more than an hour and got nothing
Lib: https://pypi.org/project/automata-lib/

Here is the TypeError and as you can see im only giving one argument and still not working
[image]

And here is the method

[image]

Comment: The `validate` method you are calling in your code has nothing to do with the validate method your screenshot shows

Comment: Post code and errors as text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

Self is use to indicate a method belong to a class. It is not a argument pass to method as you did in your code.Use this link for more info:

[What is the purpose of the `self` parameter? Why is it needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-self-parameter-why-is-it-needed)